# Php sessions switch image

Tags: php, image, session, swap

i have an home button on my website, this home button is a image of a house. But i want to make my website a userfriendly website. So if someone is clicking on the button the home button is changing from color and opens the homepage. So the person knows on which page he/she is. This is my code so far.

The problem of my script it that it won't switch from image i'm not an expert in PHP sessions scripting, so could you help me out? I searched google and everything but couldn't find anything related to my question.

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['1'] = $_GET["Active"];
        if (!empty($_GET["Active"])){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/survey/sa/index")."home"; ?>">
            <img src='<?php echo $sImageURL;?>home1.png' alt='<?php $clang->eT("Default administration page");?>' width='<?php echo $iconsize;?>' height='<?php echo $iconsize;?>'/></a>
        <?php
        } 
        else{?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/survey/sa/index").""  ?>">
            <img src='<?php echo $sImageURL;?>home.png' alt='<?php $clang->eT("Default administration page");?>' width='<?php echo $iconsize;?>' height='<?php echo $iconsize;?>'/></a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Isn't this the fourth time you've asked this question?

Comment: I would like to point out that that is not a good thing. Posting duplicate questions is not appreciated on this Q and A. In fact, having your questions closed repeatedly might well lead to a question ban. Which would mean that the site would no longer allow you to ask any questions. So please keep that in mind. Ask the questions once and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know, what you need the session for. It seams to be useless, if you "read" $_GET array. I also don't know your query string state, but you could try:

```
if (isset($_GET["Active"])) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: because the image has a link, so when the site refreshes the image color change stays.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your question: You want to switch an image from "home1" to "home" when a user is on the "homepage" (root site)? Like some kind of "active" thing?

What are you using to navigate between the sites? PHPs URL syntax $_GET? If so, you could just check if the user is on the designated site, and then display the link accordingly.

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page == "" || $page == "home"){
        //User is on the default site (url: mysite.com/)
        echo "<img code....>";
    }elseif($page == "about")
        //User is on the "about site" (url: mysite.com/?page=about)
        echo "<img active about>";
    }else{
        //The user is on a unknown site (url: mysite.com/?page=<something we don't know>)
    }
?>
```

Comment: That seems like it would work, however im using the YII Framework, have you got any idea how I could do this in this framework? Currently trying it out but its not working yet. Thanks alot already!